# Going from VisualStudio (C++) to Matlab

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, mex

I have written a Webcam application in VisualStudio (C++) that captures the feed of a webcam and shows it in a window using the opencv package. I can compile and run the solution without any issues. I have also written the code in Matlab MEX and compiled it using the C++ compiler from VisualStudio, but nothing happens when I run the MEX-file. How do I get the window to appear using the MEX file?

This is for a larger app (created in Matlab app-design) where I need to be able to snapshot images using the webcam. It is currently running the .exe file of the webcam-program compiled in VS, but I would like to chage this to a MEX function in order to be able to compile the app I'm working on.

The program compiled in VS:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    //Open the default video camera
    VideoCapture cap(0);

    // if not success, exit program
    if (cap.isOpened() == false)
    {
        cout << "Cannot open the video camera" << endl;
        cin.get(); //wait for any key press
        return -1;
    }

    double dWidth = cap.get(CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH); //get the width of frames of the video
    double dHeight = cap.get(CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT); //get the height of frames of the video

    cout << "Resolution of the video : " << dWidth << " x " << dHeight << endl;

    string window_name = "My Camera Feed";
    namedWindow(window_name); //create a window called "My Camera Feed"

    while (true)
    {
        Mat frame;
        bool bSuccess = cap.read(frame); // read a new frame from video 

        //Breaking the while loop if the frames cannot be captured
        if (bSuccess == false)
        {
            cout << "Video camera is disconnected" << endl;
            cin.get(); //Wait for any key press
            break;
        }

        //show the frame in the created window
        imshow(window_name, frame);

        //wait for for 10 ms until any key is pressed.  
        //If the 'Esc' key is pressed, break the while loop.
        //If the any other key is pressed, continue the loop 
        //If any key is not pressed withing 10 ms, continue the loop 
        if (waitKey(10) == 27)
        {
            cout << "Esc key is pressed by user. Stoppig the video" << endl;
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;

}
```

The program in Matlab:

```
/* webcam
 * Runs webcam from matlab
 * capture window: ctrl + c
 * end window: esc
 */

#include "mex.hpp"
#include "mexAdapter.hpp"
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
using namespace matlab::data;
using matlab::mex::ArgumentList;

class MexFunction : public matlab::mex::Function {
public:
    int operator()() {
        //Open the default video camera
    VideoCapture cap(0);

    // if not success, exit program
    if (cap.isOpened() == false)
    {
        cout << "Cannot open the video camera" << endl;
        cin.get(); //wait for any key press
        return -1;
    }

    double dWidth = cap.get(CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH); //get the width of frames of the video
    double dHeight = cap.get(CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT); //get the height of frames of the video

    cout << "Resolution of the video : " << dWidth << " x " << dHeight << endl;

    string window_name = "My Camera Feed";
    namedWindow(window_name); //create a window called "My Camera Feed"

    while (true)
    {
        Mat frame;
        bool bSuccess = cap.read(frame); // read a new frame from video 

        //Breaking the while loop if the frames cannot be captured
        if (bSuccess == false)
        {
            cout << "Video camera is disconnected" << endl;
            cin.get(); //Wait for any key press
            break;
        }

        //show the frame in the created window
        imshow(window_name, frame);

        //wait for for 10 ms until any key is pressed.  
        //If the 'Esc' key is pressed, break the while loop.
        //If the any other key is pressed, continue the loop 
        //If any key is not pressed withing 10 ms, continue the loop 
        if (waitKey(10) == 27)
        {
            cout << "Esc key is pressed by user. Stoppig the video" << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
    }

};
```

I have compiled the program in Matlab using the command:

```
mex webcamCversion.cpp -I'C:\opencv\build\include\'
```

I would expect to see a window opening up with the webcam feed, but nothing happens when I run the matlab version of the program.

Comment: Have you tried debugging it?

Comment: How do I debug it? I don't get any errors when I run the compiled version of the file. And I can't run the .cpp file containing the MEX functions in Matlab.

Comment: You can debug it using VS, just like any other C++ program. See [](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/debugging-on-microsoft-windows-platforms.html)